# EF - Add to an association set by Id

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, associations

Say I have a many to many relationship:

```
Song  *---*  Artist
```

I'm at a point in my code where I want to add an artist to the song.  I know the artist's ID, but I don't have an instance of the `Artist` entity.

Currently I have to do something like:

```
var artist = context.Artists.Single(a => a.Id == artistId);
song.Artists.Add(artist);
```

This involves a DB query.

The many-to-many relationship is modelled as a table:

```
SongId | ArtistId
-------+---------
```

What I'd like to do, for performance reasons, is to just add an entry to this table without having to go to the DB to load a bunch of entity data that I don't need.

Is there a way to do this with EF?  For example, an API like this:

```
song.Artists.Add(artistId);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dummy object:

```
var song = context.Songs.Single(s => s.Id == songId);
var artist = new Artist { Id = artistId };
context.Artists.Attach(artist);
song.Artists.Add(artist);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll try this out asap.  So this doesn't pull any extra data down for the dummy entity?  Thanks very much!

Comment: No, dummy entity is just placeholder for entity key (primary key) data.

Comment: A very nice solution, thanks again.  It's a smart way of specifying the entity key too, which I suppose could be of any type (or maybe even composite, though I haven't tried that yet.)